# Unable to install Rails 4.0 on Windows OS -- command prompt hangs upon 'building native extensions'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I currently have a Rails 4.0 app that I would like to test on a local server. However, all I had was Rails 3.2 (With Ruby 1.9.3). So I decided to install Ruby 2.0.0 (64 bit) and run

```
gem install rails -V
```

Upon reaching `'Building native extensions'`, a seeming blank command prompt screen opens and closes very quickly, and no further progress is made (I waited for 45 minutes). 
If I force close the program, and retry the command, an error would appear, saying that `MakeFiles failed to completely run`. This problem is caused by `conftest.exe` still being run by the first command and it cannot be forced closed through `Task Manager`. Also, I am unable to close this command prompt window, and the only way to close it is through shutting down, or by ending `conhost.exe`, but the latter results in conftest still running.

I also tried to update my 3.2 rails installation and the same error occurs.

I currently have `Ruby 1.9.3` with Rails `3.2` (Installed through `RailsInstaller`), as well as Ruby 2.0.0 (DevKit installed). 
I essentially have two problems:

1. Inability to install Rails 4.0
2. Being unable to properly close the command prompt when it hangs.

I recognized the fact that **it is not recommended to instal RoR on Windows**, but I would like to leave installing Ubuntu as a last resort.

Comment: Hi sorry for my bad formatting -- first stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby Installer site](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) says this specifically:

> Ruby 2.0.0, specially the 64bits version, are relatively new on the
>   Windows area and not all the packages have been updated to be
>   compatible with it. To use this version you will require some
>   knowledge about compilers and solving dependency issues, which might
>   be too complicated if you just want to play with the language.

I'm currently running Rails 4.0 on my Windows 8 system.  Rails installed for me just fine(with a complication or two following the initial install), and I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.  I'd recommend that you downgrade to that version and try it.  Rails 4 does not require Ruby 2.0 although it is preferred, and they claim that Rails 5 will require it, but for now 1.9.3 works just fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, however, as stated above I also have already tried to install rails 4 on ruby 1.9.3 that came with RailsInstaller and the same problem occurs.